# Stringizing operator in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, llvm

I am trying to use the stringizing operator #, but I get the error `stray ‘#’ in program`. Here is how I am using it.

```
#define STR "SOME_STRING"
#define BM 8
#define NUM_OF_THREADS 8
#define VER_STR (STR #BM #NUM_THREADS)
```

I expect to get `SOME_STRING88` for `VER_STR` but instead get an error. What mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to turn the numerical constants into a string. However, `#BM` is an error, since the syntax is only valid for macro parameters.
So you need to force en expansion through an intermediate macro. And you may as well have a STRINGIFY macro to do it:

```
#include <iostream>

#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)

#define STR "SOME_STRING"
#define BM 8
#define S_BM STRINGIFY(BM)
#define NUM_OF_THREADS 8
#define S_NUM_OF_THREADS STRINGIFY(NUM_OF_THREADS)
#define VER_STR STR S_BM S_NUM_OF_THREADS

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::cout << VER_STR;
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the above in action at http://ideone.com/cR1KZP

**EDIT**

As Magnus Hoff pointed out, you can invoke STRINGIFY directly as well:

```
#define VER_STR STR STRINGIFY(BM) STRINGIFY(NUM_OF_THREADS)
```

Comment: `#BM` doesn't give `"BM"`, it gives a compilation error. `#` can only be used on parameters of function-style macros.

Comment: @Angew, fixed. I had an incomplete solution in mind while writing it.

Comment: For completeness: It also works without the intermediate `S_...`-macros, with `#define VER_STR STR STRINGIFY(BM) STRINGIFY(NUM_OF_THREADS)`: http://ideone.com/hbBQIp

Comment: @MagnusHoff, Yes of course. It's just my compulsive need to keep the lines short :)