# Error reading the Git commit hash into C++

Tags: c++, git, cmake

I'm trying to read the Git commit hash into a C++ application. Using the following CMakeList file I get the correct commit hash.

CMakelist

```
  FIND_PACKAGE(Git)
  IF(GIT_FOUND)
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(
      COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} rev-parse --short HEAD
      WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
      OUTPUT_VARIABLE COMMIT
      OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Commit : ${COMMIT}" )
  ELSE(GIT_FOUND)
    SET(COMMIT 0)
  ENDIF(GIT_FOUND)

set(yada "${COMMIT}")
MESSAGE("lkpoopkpoef".${yada})
add_definitions("-D_GIT_COMMIT_HASH=${yada}")
```

However, when I try to read the value in C++ in the following function, I get an error.

main.cpp

```
std::string getGitCommit()
{
    #ifdef _GIT_COMMIT_HASH
    return _GIT_COMMIT_HASH;
    #endif
    return "unavailable";
}
```

> In function ‘std::__cxx11::string getGitCommit()’:
>   :0:18: error: ‘d2cdfd2’ was not declared in this scope

d2cdfd2 is the commit hash.

I'm referring to

1. http://xit0.org/2013/04/cmake-use-git-branch-and-commit-details-in-project/
2. [How to read a CMake Variable in C++ source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900661/how-to-read-a-cmake-variable-in-c-source-code)

I'm trying to avoid creating another file to store the commit hash and would like to directly read this from the CMakeList.

I'm using catkin_make to build the application on an Ubuntu 16.04

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash is not actually a string.  Even the compiler error is telling you this.

You need to use the *stringize* operator (`#`).
From [Stringizing operator in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119643/stringizing-operator-in-c-c):

```
#define STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_(x)

#ifdef _GIT_COMMIT_HASH
return STRINGIFY(_GIT_COMMIT_HASH);
#endif
```

Note also that since this function always returns a string literal, it may be more appropriate for the return type to be `const char*` instead of `std::string`.  Although it's perfectly valid either way.

One other point is that if the hash is not available, your compiler may warn you that the second `return` is unreachable.  If you don't want that to happen, then use a `#else` directive:

```
#ifdef _GIT_COMMIT_HASH
return STRINGIFY(_GIT_COMMIT_HASH);
#else
return "unavailable";
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks @paddy. The answer gave me a compile error "Stray # in code". Edited the answer to solve that.

Comment: Ah of course, my apologies for a mediocre answer.  Glad you were able to correct it.